# Is it possible to iterate over the various records from a MySQL database without using two for loops?

Tags: mysql, rust

This is my code:

```
use mysql::*;
use mysql::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Persone {
    id: i32,
    email: String,
}

fn main() {
    let url = "mysql://root:9211@localhost:3306/test";
    let pool = Pool::new(url).unwrap();
    let mut conn = pool.get_conn().unwrap();

    let select_all = conn.query_map(
        "SELECT id, email FROM persone", |(id, email)| { Persone { id, email } },
    );

    for row in select_all.iter() {
        for p in row {
            println!("{} - {}", p.id, p.email);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I solved it this way:

```
for row in select_all.iter().flatten() {
    println!("{} - {}", row.id, row.email);
}
```

Comment: What would you want the code to look like if it *didn't* have two loops (one for rows, one for columns)?

Comment: Your question feels equivalent to "how do I visit every block in a city without going north-to-south **and** east-to-west".

Comment: `select_all.iter().flatten()`

Comment: [`select_all` is a `Result<Vec<_>>`](https://docs.rs/mysql/18.2.0/mysql/prelude/trait.Queryable.html#method.query_map) so [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) it and iterate over the vector: `for p in select_all.unwrap() {}`

Comment: or add proper error handling, eg. `for p in select_all? {}`

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: months ago someone told me the exact opposite.

Comment: @matteo I'm afraid that someone has deluded you. It is common practice to put answers as answers, and highly discouraged to have the answer in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to handle [error returned from `query_map`](https://docs.rs/mysql/18.2.0/mysql/prelude/trait.Queryable.html#method.query_map), e.g. with the [`?` (try)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) operator.

You're accidentally iterating over `Result` as if it was a collection, but that's a very unusual way of using it. `iter().flatten()` on a `Result` is a bad idea, unless you intend to silently ignore errors.